# Numpy: trouble obtaining a 2D slice of 3D array

Tags: python, numpy, 3d, slice

Similar questions have been asked on SO, but never in the form that I needed.

I seem to be having trouble understanding NumPy slicing behavior.

Lets say I have an Numpy Array of shape 512x512x120

```
vol1=some_numpy_array
print(x.shape) #result: (512,512,120)
```

I want to take a "z-slice" of this array, however I end up with a 512x120 array instead of a 512x512 one
I try the following code for instance

```
zSlice=(vol1[:][:][2]).squeeze()
print(zSlice.shape()) #result: (512,120)
```

Why is the resulting array shape `(512,120)` and not `(512,512)`? How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to slice at once:

```
vol1[:, :, 2].squeeze()
```

---

```
>>> vol1[:, :, 2].squeeze().shape
(512, 512)
```

Because doing `[:]` repeatedly doesn't do anything:

```
>>> (vol1[:][:] == vol1).all()
True
>>>
```

It's because `[:]` gets the whole of the list... doing it multiple times does not change anything.

Comment: I upvoted and accept, but it will only accept one, Both answer are basically the same, so I accepted the other one, since its first on my page

Comment: Do you know why this indexing works when not slicing though (e.g. `vol1[x][y][z]`) ?

Comment: @MichaelSohnen Because `[:]` slicing does not change the array, whereas if you do something like `[:2]` it would change the array, not only indexing :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `vol1[:][:][2]` is:
`vol1[:]` will give the entire array, then again `[:]` gives the entire array, and finally `[2]` gives the array at index 2 to in the outer axis, eventually `vol1[:][:][2]` is nothing but `vol1[2]` which is not what you want.

You need to take numpy array slice:

```py
vol1[:, :, 2].
```

Now, it will take all the items from outermost, and outer axes, but only item at index 2 for the inner most axis.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense, but it seems strange, because when NOT slicing, the indexing works as expected `vol1[x][y][z]` will give the same value as `vol1[x,y,z]`.

Comment: @MichaelSohnen, That is true, because `vol1[x][y][z]` works at one index at each axis so is same to `vol1[x,y,z]`, but `[:]` takes the entire array slice so is different.

Comment: I see now... the first and subsequent [:] each return a multidimensional array identical to the original in shape and value. I don't know why I thought numpy would unwrap one layer from the array for each [:], perhaps because this is what would happen with normal lists.